# Answer this and you're a true genius: Error removing then re-adding missing reference

Tags: vba, excel, reference, runtime

```
    Dim brokenRef As VBIDE.Reference
    Dim refrnc As VBIDE.Reference
    For Each refrnc In vbProj.References
        If refrnc.GUID = "{C94A4194-E621-404A-8E20-447E4D415ABD}" Then
            found = True
            If refrnc.IsBroken Then
                found = False
                Set brokenRef = refrnc
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not found Then
        If Not brokenRef Is Nothing Then vbProj.References.Remove brokenRef 'THISLINE'
        vbProj.References.AddFromFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "NuancePDF.tlb"
    End If
```

I am looking for a missing reference and then attempting to add it. I got some error when adding it, so I figured it must be because the reference is there, it is just broken, so I try to remove the reference and I get the error on that line (this line). The error description is given in the image. As background, I want to automate the process of adding references since some machines cannot find them. This runs in the workbook_open sub so it seems to run this sub before compiling the rest, which relies on the references and so for some reason I am not getting a compile error because of a missing reference, but if it works idc.

I read online about running regedit in the cmd, and then deleting some stuff. However I do not fully understand what they were doing and I am working on company computers and so I do not want to risk messing anything up.

[image]

Comment: FYI `ThisWorkbook.Path` doesn't include a trailing "\", so you need to add that.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308340/how-to-check-and-remove-incorrect-project-references-in-the-visual-bas  "On the Tools menu, click References and then add a reference to the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library. This library contains objects that refer to the VBA projects.  Before you click OK, you must verify that the new reference is added above the "missing" reference. Click the arrow several times to change the priority, move the new reference above the "missing" reference, and then click OK."  Did you promote the reference to this library?

Comment: Yea I know about the"\" it got removed but thanks. I have added that ref but it is at the bottom, below the missing ref. I wonder if that is it. I can try it in 2 minutes I cannot on this computer and I will let you know what happens. If I raise the priority of this reference will that apply to all other computers that open the file?

Comment: @TimWilliams I raised the priority of the reference and I get a different error that I was getting before. "Run time error '-2147319779 (8002801d)': Automation Error Library not registered." Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here (2014) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b90ed5cc-6bd1-46b4-bbea-de4a15521b26/detect-and-remove-missing-references-in-vba-code?forum=exceldev   Seems like there may not be a workable solution to this.

Comment: IMO this is a flawed approach. Late binding is generally **much** simpler.

Comment: I am a true genius..,, add a bounty ... and I will answer it.

Comment: How exactly does late bounding help here? @Rory My guess is that you still need to add the reference, but that it will compile without needing the reference, and you add it at runtime? How accurate is that? Also Tim Williams, I read that link and a person mentioned how they started without it and then added it, which although not ideal, seems to work for me.

Comment: @TimWilliams ^^

Comment: If you late bind, you don't set a reference at all. That's the point of it.

Comment: @Rory excuse my ignorance of this material lol but how is that possible, where does it find the methods associated with an object described by the PDFPlus reference? Does it search for it upon creating the object? That seems unlikely since when I search for the file it takes like 10 minutes given I am searching a large server, although I am searching a very broad region.

Comment: It queries the object at run time. I don't know what searching for a file has to do with anything.

Comment: @Rory apologies I don't know as much. What does it mean to query the object? Maybe I misunderstand the idea of a reference. My thoughts in searching for a file were this: a reference I assumed is like a library or set of classes or whatever that contains info about the Nuance object. Windows will not inherently have that information so by adding the reference file it knows where those methods and properties of the object are defined and how they work. So it needs to get that information somewhere, it cannot just make it up? So I figured it had to search for this information.

Comment: At runtime it will query the object and say effectively "can you do this?". It runs a little slower as a result, but you avoid the reference issue.

Comment: It looks at class types in the Registry to find the library.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I don't fully understand the point of references I think then. I will do some research.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of solved, see the comments. The link posted by Tim Williams gives a good idea which is to start without the reference and then add it, which I guess is maybe similar to late binding in a way. As for getting what I wanted to explicitly work it seems that you have to register it via regsvr32 in the cmd, which is not working for me.